# Node Config file setup to connect with database using sequelize and enviroment variables

Tags: node.js, database, configuration, environment-variables, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize configuration file that I use to connect with DB:

**config/database.js**

```
const config = require('./config');

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: config.CONFIG.db_user,
    password: config.CONFIG.db_password,
    database: config.CONFIG.db_name,
    host: config.CONFIG.db_host,
    dialect: config.CONFIG.db_dialect,
    port: config.CONFIG.db_port
  },
  test: {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    database: 'db_test',
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
  },
  production: {
    username: config.CONFIG.db_user,
    password: config.CONFIG.db_password,
    database: config.CONFIG.db_name,
    host: config.CONFIG.db_host,
    dialect: config.CONFIG.db_dialect
  }
};
```

in the sequelize model index.js file I want to set the enviroment I need by passing a `env` variable to the previous file:

**models/index.js**

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const dbConfig = require('../config/database');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  dbConfig.test.database,
  dbConfig.test.username,
  dbConfig.test.password, {
    host: dbConfig.test.host,
    dialect: dbConfig.test.dialect,
    port: dbConfig.test.port
  });
```

now I do it manually, there's a way to do it programmatically? thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
module.exports = function () {

    let development = {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    database: 'db_test',
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'};

    let production = {
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    database: 'db_test',
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql'
  };


    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
        case 'development':
            return development;

        case 'production':
            return production;

        default:
            return development;
    }
};
```

You can access the environment variables anywhere in your code like this:

```
process.env.var_name
```